# files not updating in localhost after restart

Tags: html, css

I'm a beginner in PHP and i started coding the PHP part of my webpage yesterday everything was fine i moved all my html files to a new folder and saved them as php. However today when i turned on my computer and started doing some work on CSS of the web pages and tested these in browser then nothing was being updated.

I even added `http://localhost:1234/..` at the beginning of href in link to CSS file. I moved my CSS files in the same folder but nothing is updating.

Yesterday when i opened `http://localhost:1234/websiteName/`

" it would show a file directory like page to browse the files today it isnt even showing that. I am using XAMPP and it is working fine. 
Is there a solution?

Thank You

Comment: Have you tried clearing your browser caches?

Comment: @codehitman not really

Comment: The webserver is on port 80 and 443 (SSL).

Comment: @Zain Try clearing your browser caches and then refresh the page

Comment: @codehitman okay thank you it worked so do i have to clear my browsing cache after every single time i plan to test the webpage in browser?

Comment: Yes. But you could send a cache-control header to tell the browser to not cache the page.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois how?

Comment: Well, I'm just telling the browser to revalidate everything. `header("Cache-Control: max-age: 600, must-revalidate");`

Comment: @CharlotteDunois sorry for stupid questions, I am a beginner. This goes into JavaScript under (document).ready() ?

Comment: No, you have to put this in your php script, before you're making any outputs.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois oh okay right after <body> tag maybe?

Comment: You can put it anywhere, as long as you do it before printing anything to the output.

Comment: Most likely problem? Xampp isn't running.

Answer (score 0):

To formalize the answer:

- Clear your browser cache history.
- You can also add the following line of `php` code anywhere in your php file:

  ```
  header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate"); // HTTP/1.1
  ```

You can find the documentation for it on [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) page.